# lighttpd as reverse-proxy

Tags: lighttpd, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

DeviceA serves as a reverse-proxy and is supposed to forward requests as follows:

**192.168.1.10/DeviceB ==> 192.168.1.20/index.html**

**192.168.1.10/DeviceC ==> 192.168.1.30/index.html**

Both index files are located under /var/www and are static "Hello world!" pages. The problem is that I can't access those files through DeviceA, but if I call a test service also running on DeviceC (listening on port 12345) everything works fine.

Am I wrong saying that the web server on DeviceB, DeviceC should respond with index.html if a request comes in on port 80 ???

*lighttpd.conf DeviceA @192.168.1.10*
    server.modules = ( "mod_proxy" )

```
proxy.server = ( 
"/DeviceB" => ( "" => ( "host" => "192.168.1.20", "port" => 80 )),
"/DeviceC" => ( "" => ( "host" => "192.168.1.30", "port" => 80 )),  
"/TestService" => ( "" => ( "host" => "192.168.1.30", "port" => 12345 ))
)
```

*lighttpd.conf DeviceB @192.168.1.20*

```
server.document-root = "/var/www"
server.port = 80
index-file.names = ( "index.html" )
```

*lighttpd.conf DeviceC @192.168.1.30*

```
server.document-root = "/var/www"
server.port = 80
index-file.names = ( "index.html" )
```

---

**Update**

Do I need $HTTP["host"] == ... around proxy.server() to rewrite/redirect URLs? Or, how to define what shall be proxy(ed)

Comment: Should be on serverfault, not SO

Comment: What's the question here?  I've got no problem helping with Lighttpd, but I see a lot of setup and no real question (at least that makes sense given the setup)...?

Comment: The question was how to setup proxy.server() in order to forward 192.168.1.10/DeviceB requests to 192.168.1.20/index.html

Answer (score 19):

Your need is known by lighttpd developers from several years.

It is answered by a workaround or new feature depending on the version.

**Lighttpd 1.4**

A workaround is explained in the bugtracker : [bug #164](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/164#note-9)

> ```
> $HTTP["url"] =~ "(^/DeviceB/)" {   
>   proxy.server  = ( "" => ("" => ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 81 ))) 
> }
>
> $SERVER["socket"] == ":81" {   
>   url.rewrite-once = ( "^/DeviceB/(.*)$" => "/$1" )   
>   proxy.server  = ( "" => ( "" => ( "host" => "192.168.1.20", "port" => 80 ))) 
> }
> ```

**Lighttpd 1.5**

They added this feature with this command ([official documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxyCore)) :

> **proxy-core.rewrite-request** : rewrite request headers or request uri.
>
> ```
> $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/DeviceB" {
>   proxy-co...
>
>   proxy-core.rewrite-request = (
>     "_uri" => ( "^/DeviceB/?(.*)" => "/$1" ),
>     "Host" => ( ".*" => "192.168.1.20" ),
>   )
> }
> ```

Answer (score 6):

**Required package**

```
server.modules  =  (
...
   "mod_proxy",
...
)
```

**Your frontend proxy setting : for lighttpd.conf  @192.168.1.10**

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^.*DeviceB" {
    proxy.server  = ( "" => 
        (( "host" => "192.168.1.20", "port" => 80 ))
    )
}

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^.*DeviceC" {
    proxy.server  = ( "" => 
        (( "host" => "192.168.1.30", "port" => 80 ))
    )
}
```

For the full documentation of lighttpd mod_proxy, you can refer to http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModProxy

Answer (score 0):

Another, non-workaround solution for **Lighttpd 1.4**

Using `proxy.header` (available since version 1.4.46, tested using version 1.4.53):

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "(^/DeviceB/)" {   
  proxy.server = ( "" => ("" => ( "host" => "192.168.1.20", "port" => 80 )))
  proxy.header = (
    "map-urlpath" => ( "/DeviceB" => "" )
  )
}
```

Unfortunately, `map-urlpath` is only able to replace the prefix of the URL, but that covers most cases including this one.
For details refer to the [documentation](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Mod_proxy) of `mod_proxy`.