# Lighttpd reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, lighttpd, mod-proxy

I have a reverse proxy setting in my Apache's *httpd.conf*:

```
ProxyPass "/endpoint" "https://someurl.com/endpoint"
ProxyPassReverse "/endpoint" "https://someurl.com/endpoint"
```

And I need to replicate this in Lighttpd. I'm running a JS app which calls `localhost:8080/endpoint` to retrieve some data. I'd like to set up a proxy to **always** redirect `/endpoint` to `https://someurl.com/endpoint`.

In my *lighttpd.conf* I have the following settings:

```
server.modules = ("mod_proxy")

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^.*endpoint" {
  proxy.server = ( "" => (( "host" => "https://someurl.com/endpoint" ) ) )
}
```

based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859956/lighttpd-as-reverse-proxy).
I have also tried:

```
server.modules = ("mod_proxy")
proxy.server = ( "/endpoint" => (( "host" => "https://someurl.com/endpoint" )))
```

based on the [lighttpd docs](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxy).

In both cases, I'm still hitting `localhost:8080/endpoint` which results in a 404 error. How do I set up the proxy correctly?

Answer (score 4):

In lighttpd 1.4.46 and later, you can use `proxy.header`.  See
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy

```
server.modules = ("mod_proxy")
$HTTP["url"] == "/endpoint" {
    proxy.server = ( "" => (( "host" => "someurl.com" )))
    proxy.header = ( "map-host-request" => ( "-" => "someurl.com"),
                     "map-host-response" => ("-" => "-"))
}
```