# Redirecting page to specific IP and port in lighttpd

Tags: redirect, lighttpd

I got 2 server under same network and I hope to redirect `domain.com/page` to `192.168.2.16:22348` so i got this in lighttpd.conf according to this: [lighttpd as reverse-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859956/lighttpd-as-reverse-proxy)

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/page" {
  proxy.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" =>  "192.168.2.16", "port" => 22348 ) ) )
}
```

but I ended up getting redirected to 192.168.2.16/maps which doesn't exist (I only got index.html but I can't change it) and returned 404.
Is there any way to only pass IP and port but not /page?

(I also tried `domain.com/google` to `google.com` by the same way but ended up to `google.com/google`)

Others I also tried:
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxy

Comment: Your have not explained your question very well.  You should edit it with a more explicit example of what request you are sending and what pseudo-request you want to send, or what response your are getting and what response you want to get.  Please be more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of using `www.domain.com/page`, i decided to use `subdomain.domain.com`.
Here's what I got.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "subdomain.domain.com" {
  proxy.server = ( "" =>  ( ( "host" => "192.168.2.16", "port" => "22348" ) ) )
}
```

Since there is nothing after `subdomain.domain.com/`, it won't pass anything but only ip and port (`192.168.2.16:22348`) so I don't need to modify anything from the second machine. I think this is easier to configure instead of using `/page`.

Answer (score 0):

> Others I also tried: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxy

I think you should look at `proxy.header` `"map-urlpath"` on the same page.